# Too Many Directories when opening a CocosBuilder project

Tags: cocosbuilder

When I open a cocosbuilder project again after I adding some new directories, it pops up a dialog that says

> Too Many Directories
>
> You have created or opened a project which is in a directory with very many sub directories. Please save your project-files in a directory together with the resources you use in your project.

I know it is because there are too many directories.

But I wonder if there is any other method that can solves this problem except removing my new added directories.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always remove the warning directly in CocosBuilder source and rebuilt it, provided that you use the github version.

Otherwise you could petition for the change [requested by MK](https://github.com/cocos2d/CocosBuilder/issues/303) on github.

The offending code is located in `CocosBuilderAppDelegate.m`, around line ~1155

```
[[CocosBuilderAppDelegate appDelegate] modalDialogTitle:@"Too Many [...]
```

You will have to remove this line in at least two places.

```
- (void) checkForTooManyDirectoriesInCurrentDoc
{
    if (!currentDocument) return;

    if ([ResourceManager sharedManager].tooManyDirectoriesAdded)
    {
        // Close document if it has too many sub directories
        NSTabViewItem* item = [self tabViewItemFromDoc:currentDocument];
        [tabView removeTabViewItem:item];

        [ResourceManager sharedManager].tooManyDirectoriesAdded = NO;

        // Notify the user
        [[CocosBuilderAppDelegate appDelegate] modalDialogTitle:@"Too Many Directories" message:@"You have created or opened a file which is in a directory with very many sub directories. Please save your ccb-files in a directory together with the resources you use in your project."];
    }
}

- (BOOL) checkForTooManyDirectoriesInCurrentProject
{
    if (!projectSettings) return NO;

    if ([ResourceManager sharedManager].tooManyDirectoriesAdded)
    {
        [self closeProject];

        [ResourceManager sharedManager].tooManyDirectoriesAdded = NO;

        // Notify the user
        [[CocosBuilderAppDelegate appDelegate] modalDialogTitle:@"Too Many Directories" message:@"You have created or opened a project which is in a directory with very many sub directories. Please save your project-files in a directory together with the resources you use in your project."];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

### Update:

In **CocosBuilder/ccBuilder/ResourceManager.h**

There is a marco defined as below:

```
#define kCCBMaxTrackedDirectories 50
```

So we can simply change `50` to **a larger number**, and the problem can be solved.

Comment: And where is 'the warning' in CocosBuilder source?

Comment: I tried remove these line, though I can successfully open the project, but I can't see the file in the directories behind. And from this point I find there is a marco define the max value of the directories in one project. So I will update it in your post.